# How to run nutch in production enviornment

Tags: nutch

I was experimenting some crawl cycles with nutch and would like to setup a distributed crawl environment. But I wonder how can I trigger nutch for incoming crawl requests in a production system. I read about nutch REST api. Is that the real option that I have ? Or can I run nutch as a continuously running distributed server by any other option ?

My preferred nutch version is nutch 1.12.

Comment: The REST api is a good option if you want to have Nutch running on a remote server and still be able to launch crawls and monitor status. 
If you dont want to do that then you can launch crawls using the command line. To understand your question better, why do you not want to use the REST api ?

Comment: I've tried REST api and it works well. But I want to know whether that's the best option in production?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As sujen stated, there are two options for this :-

1. Use REST api if you want to submit crawl requests to nutch remotely.
   Steps to get this running is described here :-

[How to run nutch server on distributed environment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39761712/how-to-run-nutch-server-on-distributed-environment)

2. Otherwise you can run bin/crawl script from runtime/deploy to launch requests to nutch distributed using hadoop.