# How to run nutch server on distributed environment

Tags: nutch

I have tested running of nutch in server mode by starting it using bin/nutch startserver command *locally*. Now I wonder whether I can start nutch in *server mode* on top of a hadoop cluster(in distributed environment) and submit crawl requests to server using nutch REST api ?
Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From further research I've got nutch server working on distributed mode.

Steps :-

1. Assume hadoop is configured in all slave nodes. Then setup nutch in all nodes. This can help : http://wiki.apache.org/nutch/NutchHadoopTutorial
2. On your namenode, `cd $NUTCH_HOME/runtime/deploy`
3. `bin/nutch startserver -port <port> -host <host>`
   Note :Port and host are optional.
4. Then you can submit requests from nutch using REST. The requests you submit will be accepted by nutch server started on step 3.

Happy crawling :)